# is there a way to iterate through array, listing each item in fixed-height container until all available space taken?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox, v-for

Using Vue, I have a div container with fixed height, overflow: hidden, I want to iterate through javascript array, adding each item to the div, and stop when the bottom of the div space is reached. Would also need it to be responsive.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="body" v-for="item in items">
    <div>{{ item.data }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Maybe you would need to retrieve the height of the container in pixels and divide by font height of your item.data perhaps? In any case the number of items displayed would need to change whenever window is resized in order to make it responsive.

Comment: look for a property that is related to the scroll bar ... it may exist even if the scrollbar is not visible

Comment: Any reason to do it actively rather than just create them all and then set overflow-y: hidden? That way you don't have to enter JS every time there is a resize. Have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could do it like you are doing it, and use element.offsetHeight to know when you've gone too far
2. You could set CSS property `max-height` to set a max height (you might also want to set the `overflow-y` property)
3. You could use a `SELECT` and set the `size` attribute on that